# Is there any good database for aircraft technical specifications?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance, aircraft-systems, datasets

Due to using them in my application, I am looking for a database(or guide) of aircraft technical specifications. Is there any source for it(preferably free).

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! This seems like a very broad topic, are you interested in some specific type of aircraft?

Comment: @Pondliffe, thank you. I am interested all kind of active aircraft. I try to create a quick guide for users who are interested in finding proper aircraft according to their demands.

Comment: What kind of technical specifications are you looking for? Manufacturer published marketing specifications such as speed and range? Flight operating specifications such as flap and gear speeds or CG range? Maintenance specifications such as brake wear limits?

Comment: At the beginning, I would like to have basic specifications such as speed, range, etc. Afterward, It 'd be good to have more details.

Answer (score 4):

One word for the definitive authority on this subject: [Jane's](http://www.janes.com).  They'll get you anything you want to know - if the price is right.

Another good source, especially for military aircraft is The [Military Analysis Network](https://fas.org/man/index.html), run the Federation of American Scientists (FAS).  Great information database and it's free, too!

As with so many other subjects, [Wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org) remains an excellent source of information on aircraft.  It is not a recommended source to cite for writing technical publications of your own, but is a excellent internet portal to additional information and resources e.g. books, periodical articles, etc.

Comment: I've always figured Jane's must employ a network of spies and informants to get the data they have. I would look at their diff and think there's no way the military wants this stuff to be public knowledge

Comment: +1 for Jane's - the aeronautical engineer's bible! Worth adding the best place to view a copy for free is a university library.

Comment: It is worth noting, however, that, while ubiquitous and amazingly thorough, Janes is not something to take at face value.  I worked for a short while at Sikorsky Aircraft doing competitive analysis and typically found that, while they are true, the performance characteristics are either recorded for a vague flight condition, different flight conditions, or something else of the sort.  You have to very careful in order to use Janes and still compare apples to apples.